# Is there a way to fetch the date/time in Javascript without restarting the app?

Tags: javascript, discord, discord.js

I was wondering if I can fetch the current date/time in JavaScript without restarting my bot, I used the Date() function but it wasn't much useful cause I would need to restart the app everyday for fetching the data

Edit 3
The code is working without crashing

```
const Discord = require('discord.js');
const { Client, MessageAttachment } = require('discord.js');
const client = new Discord.Client();


client.once('ready', () => {
    console.log("Ready!")
})

client.on('message', message =>{
    msg = message.content.toLowerCase();
 let today = new Date();
 let date = today.getDate()+"-"+(today.getMonth()+1)+"-"+today.getHours()+":"+today.getMinutes();
 let year=today.getFullYear();
setInterval(alert,10000)
    function alert(){
    today = new Date();
        date=today.getDate()+"-"+(today.getMonth()+1)+"-"+today.getHours()+":"+today.getMinutes();
        year=today.getFullYear();
}
    console.log(message.content);

     if(msg===(`hello there`)){
        message.channel.send(`General Kenobi`)
    }
     if(date===(`19-11-00:00`)){
         var birthday = year-2007;
         message.channel.send(`Happy Birthday Drake's Fortune!, Today is the ${birthday}th anniversary`)
}
)

client.login(process.env.token);
```

Comment: You just need to call `new Date();` whenever you want a new date.

Comment: Calling `new Date ()` will give you the current time every time you call it.

Comment: Ciao, can you show at least the case you need to re-fetch date/time? Give me something to work on...

Comment: `new Date()` cannot do that ?

Comment: If calling `new Date()` gives the current date, so should I create a loop which updates the date in a given interval of time?

Comment: @Photon_01 What date are you trying to update? Where are you using that date?

Comment: @Bergi I'm trying to use the date to send this type of message, "Happy Birthday {game} today is {x}th anniversary"

Comment: @Photon_01 So you're trying to schedule a job that will run every day and evaluate the date to possibly send messages? Or do you already have the code that triggers the happy-birthday message in some other way, and just need to calculate the `x` value?

Comment: Please edit your code into the question.

Comment: I've added the code

Comment: I used the ```setInterval``` function and now the Date can be updated without restarting, now my problem is resolved, thanks to everyone who took their time, contributed here :)

Answer (score 0):

Just put the `new Date()` in the `client.on('message', message =>{ });` :

```
const Discord = require('discord.js');
const { Client, MessageAttachment } = require('discord.js');
const client = new Discord.Client();

client.once('ready', () => {
    console.log("Ready!")
})

client.on('message', message =>{
    let today = new Date();
    let date = today.getDate()+"-"+(today.getMonth()+1)+"-"+today.getHours()+":"+today.getMinutes();
    let year=today.getFullYear();
    msg = message.content.toLowerCase();
    console.log(message.content);
    if(msg===(`hello there`)){
        message.channel.send(`General Kenobi`)
    }
     if(date===(`19-11-00:00`)){
         var birthday = year-2007;
         message.channel.send(`Happy Birthday Drake's Fortune!, Today is the ${birthday}th anniversary`)
}
)

client.login(process.env.token);
```

Answer (score 0):

Ok, if you are using `today, date, year` only on `client.on('message', message => {...})` function you could do:

```
client.on('message', message =>{
let today = new Date();
let date = today.getDate()+"-"+(today.getMonth()+1)+"-"+today.getHours()+":"+today.getMinutes();
let year=today.getFullYear();
msg = message.content.toLowerCase();
console.log(message.content);
 if(msg===(`hello there`)){
    message.channel.send(`General Kenobi`)
}
 if(date===(`19-11-00:00`)){
     var birthday = year-2007;
     message.channel.send(`Happy Birthday Drake's Fortune!, Today is the ${birthday}th 
     anniversary`)
 }
)
```

Comment: I was wondering would your solution update the date or should I create a loop which would update it in a fixed interval of time, anyways thanks for taking your time to answer

Comment: No problem. I think the best solution is the solution that is usefu to your purpose. If you are using `today` elsewhere the loop is the best solution. Otherwise just take Date() where you need and will be ok. Have a nice day :)